# WordPress Event Organiser calender doesn't load

Tags: wordpress, events

My Event Organiser in WordPress doesn't load since a few days. Any ideas? http://web553.login-15.loginserver.ch/unsere-welt/news/kalender/

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using another calendar solution, since I couldn't find any others.